# Getting a null value in the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem with transmitting values ​​for events. I use fullcalendar and modal to retrieve events and then through the sendAddEvent function from the calendar.js file (you can see the function below) it is sent further to CalendarController where all the values ​​except those that would be entered in the table of participants arrive, although in the sendAddEvent function in calendar.js all elements have values, and when they reach the AddEvent function in CalendarController the elements regarding the participant table have no values. Does anyone know what the cause is? Thank you.

Here is my function from the calendar.js and the variables that take values ​​from the form:

```
$('#eventModalSave').click(() => {
    const title = $('#EventTitle').val();
    const description = $('#Description').val();
    const startTime = moment($('#StartTime').val());
    const endTime = moment($('#EndTime').val());
    const color = ($('#Color').val());
    salaID = ($('#salaID').val());
    var roomID = parseInt(salaID);
    const UserId = ($('#ApplicationUserId').val());
    const isAllDay = $('#AllDay').is(":checked");
    const isNewEvent = $('#isNewEvent').val() === 'true' ? true : false;

    if (startTime > endTime) {
        alert('Ora de sfărșit a evenimentului nu poate fi mai mare decât ora de începere');

        return;
    } else if ((!startTime.isValid() || !endTime.isValid()) && !isAllDay) {
        alert('Vă rugăm să introduceți ora de început și sfărșit a evenimentului');

        return;
    }

    const event = {
        title,
        description,
        isAllDay,
        startTime: startTime._i,
        endTime: endTime._i,
        color,
        roomID,
    };
   
        
    

    if (isNewEvent) {
        sendAddEvent(event, UserId);
    } else {
        sendUpdateEvent(event, UserId);
    }
});

function sendAddEvent(event, UserId) {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Calendar/AddEvent',
        data: {
            "Title": event.title,
            "Description": event.description,
            "Start": event.startTime,
            "End": event.endTime,
            "AllDay": event.isAllDay,
            "color": event.color,
            salaID: event.roomID,
            "UserId": UserId,
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            const { message, eventId } = res.data;

            if (message === '') {
                const newEvent = {
                    start: event.startTime,
                    end: event.endTime,
                    allDay: event.isAllDay,
                    title: event.title,
                    description: event.description,
                    color: event.color,
                    salaID: event.roomID,
                    UserId: UserId,
                    
                    eventId
                };

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

                $('#eventModal').modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert(`Something went wrong: ${message}`);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => alert(`Something went wrong: ${err}`));
}
```

And here is my AddEvent function from the CallendarController where UserId has null value:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddEvent([FromBody]Event evt, [FromBody]  Participants part)
        {
            string message = String.Empty;
            int eventId = 0;
            message = AddEvent(evt,part, out eventId);
            string AddEvent(Event evt,Participants part, out int eventId)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
                SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
                eventId = 0;
                var userIdlogged = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into[Participants]
                                                    (UserId
                                                    ,EventId)
                                                   values
                                                    (@UserId
                                                     ,@eventid);
                                                 insert into [Events]
                                                (
                                                    title
                                                    ,[description]
                                                    ,event_start
                                                    ,event_end
                                                    ,all_day
                                                    ,color
                                                    ,salaID
                                                    ,ApplicationUserId
                                                )
                                                values
                                                (
                                                    @title
                                                    ,@description
                                                    ,@start
                                                    ,@end
                                                    ,@allDay
                                                    ,@color
                                                    ,@salaID
                                                    ,@ApplicationUserID
                                                );
                                                select scope_identity()", conn, trans)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = evt.Title;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = evt.Description;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = evt.Start;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Helpers.ToDBNullOrDefault(evt.End);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@allDay", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = evt.AllDay;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@color", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = evt.color;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@salaID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = evt.salaID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationUserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userIdlogged;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=part.UserId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@eventid", SqlDbType.Int).Value =eventId;
                    eventId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    message = exp.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseConnection(conn);
                }
                return message;
            }
            return Json(new { message, eventId });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to pass only one value (simple or complex type) as parameter to a Web API controller method when using the [FromBody] attribute.

Here is a worked demo showing how to pass data to controller.

Controller(TestsController):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddEvent()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddEvent(Event e,Participants p)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View(AddEvent):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddEvent";
}

<h1>AddEvent</h1>
<button onclick="AddEvent()">AddEvent</button>
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function AddEvent() {
            var event = {};
            event.Title = "Title";
            event.Description = "Description";
            event.AllDay = "AllDay";
            event.Color = "Color";
            event.SalaID = "SalaID";
            var participants = {};
            participants.UserId = "UserId";
            participants.UserName = "UserName";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Tests/AddEvent",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: { e: event, p: participants}
            })
        }
  
    </script>
}
```

Event:

```
public class Event
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AllDay { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string SalaID { get; set; }
    }
```

Participants:

```
public class Participants
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's right, I tried your method and that's how it works. The problem is that I would like to take the id of several users, and at the moment it only takes my first id from the array of ids, do you have any idea how I can do that? Thanks a lot.